# Porting cshell code to bourne shell

Tags: shell, unix

```
cat /tmp/SYSLOG | tee >( egrep -i "session limit" > sess.txt) | egrep "dst_port=3389 " > dst.txt
```

Works n C-shell but not Bourne.  I escaped the brackets and it no longer complains but it does not work. HELP!

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Are you sure that is C shell? The [`tcsh`](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/top.html) manual doesn't recognize `>( ... )` notation AFAICS.  It is a `bash` notation.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like [Process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) in `bash`.

If you're looking for genuine Bourne shell (rather than `bash`), you will have your work cut out simulating that.  In fact, your best bet would be to obtain a program that explicitly runs other programs (`pee` is one such; ISTR there being others — see [Is it possible to distribute stdin over parallel processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656927/is-it-possible-to-distribute-stdin-over-parallel-processes/) where GNU [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel) is mentioned).

If you can't do that either, then you'll have to revisit the code.  The simplest fix looks like:

```
egrep -i "session limit"  /tmp/SYSLOG > sess.txt &
egrep    "dst_port=3389 " /tmp/SYSLOG > dst.txt  &
wait
```

This runs the commands in parallel. The second `&` is unnecessary but present for symmetry. In fact, this will work in any shell, so it is the portable solution. Unless the `cat /tmp/SYSLOG` operation is actually a complex program, this works at least as neatly as the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Bourne doesn't do process substitution, i.e. `>(...)`. Use bash instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can call out to awk in your bourne shell script:

```
awk '
    tolower($0) ~ /session limit/ {print > "sess.txt"}
    /dst_port=3389 /              {print > "dst.txt"}
' /tmp/SYSLOG
```

If you happen to have GNU awk:

```
gawk -v IGNORECASE=1 '
    /session limit/  {print > "sess.txt"}
    /dst_port=3389 / {print > "dst.txt"}
' /tmp/SYSLOG
```